# How do I hide my Google plus profile picture from myself?

Tags: google-plus, google-account-profile

I use my actual face for my Google+ profile but since I'm not a narcissist, I'm already sick of seeing it *every single time* I'm using Youtube, Gmail, Maps, Calendar and of course Search.

*How can I hide visibility of my Google+ profile picture so I don't constantly see it?*

I want others to see it when searching for me online.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution that works is to:

1. Use the page information feature of your browser to examine the images on the Google Search page and locate your profile image. For Firefox this is *right click -> page info -> media tab*
2. The URL will be something like

   - `https://[a google server]/[an internal id specific to you]/[lots of gibberish]/photo.jpg`
3. Add a filter into AdBlock Plus or your tool of choice of:

   - `||*/[the internal id specific to you]/*.jpg`

Your Google+ profile picture will now be hidden from you when using the internet.